# Is it possible to sniff packets from/to chromecast dongle while doing screen mirror?

Tags: wireshark

I want to observe streams between the original screen mirrored from and the target screen mirrored to to check something like frame loss, thus I'm thinking to sniff packets between sender and receiver.

Is there any plugins for Wireshark which enables me to do that..?

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is to route the network traffic through some network node that you can sniff on. Like your laptop.

I would connect the laptop to the Internet through ethernet and make a wifi hotspot on it. Then tell chromecast to connect to your hotspot. Now you're in the middle between chromecast and the Internet. Wireshark should be able to capture the traffic without any specific plugins.

Make sure you've enabled routing between ethernet and wifi hotspot.

Comment: Thanks. I think your suggestion works for regular casting, but I want to capture media stream from google cast app to chromecast dongle while doing screen mirror, it's a different case.

Comment: Ah ok, so you want to capture and reuse the video stream? Like - display it on some 3rd place?

Comment: I hope I can do something like that~:)

Comment: That might be difficult. You'll probably have to make your own video client that can work with passive, sniffed stream. Without requests, connection initialisation, handshakes etc.